# 301 redirect DNS issues

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, nginx, redirect

I think I screwed up something in my DNS configuration and now its bugging me for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I own a domain lets call it **abc.com**

Before all the issues happened DNS was configured in the following way at my registrar:

```
abc.com         'A' record  Points to a wordpress server
www.abc.com     'A' record  Points to a wordpress server
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

We had a requirement where I had to achieve the following:

```
abc.com         point to amazon server. //not the wordpress but amazon.
www.abc.com     point to a wordpress server
app.abc.com     point to amazon server.
*.abc.com       point to amazon server
```

What I did to achieve this I believe is causing me all the issues.  I went ahead and modified the DNS records in the following order

```
abc.com         'A' record points to amazon server. //earlier pointed to wordpress
www.abc.com     'A' record points to a amazon server 
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

I changed my nginx configuration in 
such a way that

**http://*.abc.com would always redirect to https://abc.com and I made the redirect permanent**

```
server{
    listen                80; # default;
    server_name           abc.com *.abc.com;

    location / {
            include proxy_params;

            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 8192;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 256;
            return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

---

After a while I realized I made a mistake as I wanted the www.abc.com to point to wordpres. So I went ahead and modified the DNS records again.

```
abc.com         'A' record points to amazon server. 
www.abc.com     'A' record points to a wordpress //earlier pointed to amazon/nginx
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

And whatever I do, the change to www.abc.com isn't reflected on the web. It just redirects to the amazon server. I tried it using different machines, installed browsers afresh still no luck.

I tried **pinging** abc.com and www.abc.com and they do point to amazon and wordpress (as configured in DNS), I even tried checking DNS propagation at whatsmydns.com and it shows the IPs based on my DNS conf. But I don't understand why they don't work in the browser.

I tried checking the redirect flow of the site at  http://redirectcheck.com/index.php and it still shows 301 permanent redirect despite me going ahead and modifying the DNS records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check over the lists of entries again?  There's some confusing stuff like `'A' record points to a wordpress //POINTS TO AMAZON`.  To clarify - currently, the `www.` record points to the server that nginx config is on, right?  Is that the only `server` block on that nginx service?

Comment: you should consider that after changing existing DNS record it takes for that record to expire from DNS cache.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Thanks for pointing it out. I wanted the www entry to point to wordpress, but I accidentally pointed it to nginx and then modified the nginx conf to rewrite *.abc.com to https://abc.com - I later reverted it, but I cant seem to erase the rewrite. Like I mentioned in the question, I don't think its an issue with DNS propagation. pinging the domain returns the correct IP

Comment: Verify in your browser's developer tools which IP address redirect response is coming from now? For example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6EXdo.png

Comment: @ShaneMadden I did check - http://prntscr.com/55pfx9 thats the IP of the wordpress site and no where in my DNS configuration I have a 301 redirect. I have a DNS record that looks like this "www |  IP of wordpress site | A | 1800"

Comment: Then that redirect is being served by the wordpress server.  Where's it redirecting to?  Did you configure a redirect in a wordpress module or anything like that?

Comment: No, I did not change anything. It was working perfectly until I mistakenly pointed it to the amazon server and modifed nginx conf. I later reverted the change. From the screenshot its redirecting to the amazon server

Comment: @ShaneMadden thanks for the inputs. I did figure out the solution. I host my wordpress site at Mediatemple and I went ahead and cleared all the DNS related settings using their interface and the site is back up. Your suggestion about verifying the IP address using browser tools pointed me to think that something was wrong with the wordpress install. Thanks again

Comment: @ShaneMadden - But it does look weird because mediatemple (wordpress host) wasn't managing my DNS. I was using namecheap. I still dont understand how mediatemple was returning 301 when it had no business to do so.